# Get twitter and facebook shares using Reqwest.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, social-media

I'm using Reqwest.js for ajax requests, since I don't use jQuery at all
https://github.com/ded/reqwest

It looks like Reqwest supports jsonp requests, but I've some troubles with it.

Here's a code I use to get facebook and twitter shares using jQuery:

```
  // facebook
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://graph.facebook.com/http://google.com',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'JSONP'
  }).always(function(data) {
    if (data.shares) {
      alert(data.shares);
    }
  });

  // twitter
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://google.com',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'JSONP'
  }).always(function(data) {
    if (data.count) {
      alert(data.count);
    }
  });
```

jQuery code works well, jsonp works as expected.

Here's a code I use for Reqwest.js (jQuery replacement for ajax requests):

```
// facebook
reqwest({
  url: 'http://graph.facebook.com/http://google.com',
  type: 'JSONP',
  complete: function(data) {
    var response = parse(data.response);

    if (data.response && response.shares) {
      count.facebook = response.shares;
    }

    update('fb');
  }
});

// twitter
reqwest({
  url: 'http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://google.com',
  type: 'JSONP',
  complete: function(data) {
    var response = parse(data.response);

    if (data.response && response.count) {
      count.tw = response.count;
    }

    update('tw');
  }
});
```

Facebook code here works well, here's a demo `http://jsbin.com/jaxuniya/1/edit?html,js,console,output`

Twitter code returns a couple of errors, here's a demo `http://jsbin.com/tadejayi/1/edit?html,js,output`

It looks like jsonp doesn't work as expected, am I using it in a wrong way?

Here's an errors text:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 501
>   (Not Implemented)
>   `http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://google.com`
>
> Failed to load resource: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
>   present on the requested resource. Origin '`http://jsbin.com`' is
>   therefore not allowed access.
>   `http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://google.com`
>
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   `http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://google.com.`
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin '`http://jsbin.com`' is therefore not allowed access.
>   1:1
>
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input 1:1 (JSON.parse)

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

The error inspection says too obvious things:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 501 (Not Implemented) http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://google.com

- It seems like the server can not digest the request method, I it seems reasonable because you did specify the request type with the jQuery method `type: 'GET'` but with your Reqwest method you did not. As a workaround, and first library sight says you need to add `method: 'get'`:

  // facebook
  reqwest({
    url: 'http://graph.facebook.com/http://google.com',
    method: 'get',
    type: 'JSONP',
    complete: function(data) {
      var response = parse(data.response);
      if (data.response && response.shares) {
        count.facebook = response.shares;
      }
      update('fb');
    }
  });

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://google.com. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://jsbin.com' is therefore not allowed access. 1:1

- You are trying to achieve a cross domain request and that used to work with `jQuery` code because you specified the `dataType` with **jsonp** as value. Try the following:

  ```
  // twitter
  reqwest({
    url: 'http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://google.com',
    type: 'JSONP',
    jsonpCallback: 'url',
    jsonpCallbackName: 'http://google.com',
    complete: function(data) {
      var response = parse(data.response);
      if (data.response && response.count) {
        count.tw = response.count;
      }
      update('tw');
    }
  });
  ```

Comment: `type: 'JSONP'` is a way to make jsonp requests with reqwest.js. I've  also tried to add `method:'get'`, but it doesn't help. Any further ideas?

Comment: Sorry but seems impossible for the time being as I'm overburdened, maybe in few hours or few days.